# Use Google Drive API to view files in a particular folder of an account

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

I have a Google account that has access to several shared folders. Each of them has information about a particular customer. I want to develop a web application that enables my clients to log in and view the contents in their folder. I know that one solution would be to just share the folder with the client, but I need the client to interact with these files exclusively through the website (not through Google Drive) although the files are hosted in Google Drive. The client should only be allowed to READ or download the files, but not edit them.

All the examples I have seen so far about the Google Drive API involve the client logging in to HIS Google Drive account. However, I would like to develop an application that logs in to a particular Google Drive account that I know has the folders with each customer's files. Then I would just show the files for that particular customer.

Is this possible? Logging in through the API always to the same account and retrieving the files in certain folder.

I am new to the Drive API.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical